# Why typescript is not giving me the type mismatch error, which it supposed to (according to my understanding)

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Basically I am a javascript developer and after many recommendations from fellow devs I started trying typescript (which I found completely unnecessary, no offence), below is my code which has an array `arr` of `any` type and a variable `squares` which is initialized with the array returned by `map` function called on `arr` and its `callback` takes the input of type `number` and returns value of type `number` but when `arr` contains a `string` which it can since its of `any` type, instead of giving the type error I am getting NaN in that place.. please consider the code below

```
let arr : Array<any> = [1,2,3,4,'sachin',5,6,7,'naregal',8,9]

let squares = arr.map( (num : number) : number => num * num )

console.log(squares)
```

`output : [ 1, 4, 9, 16, NaN, 25, 36, 49, NaN, 64, 81 ]`

Comment: Because typescript compiles to javascript at runtime and javascript actually has no types. So multiplying two strings gives NaN instead of type error

Comment: Typescript provides compile time safety, which you sort of disabled with using `any`. At runtime you are running js which has no concept of typed arrays or typed function parameter and does how it's defined: when told to multiply something that's not a number, return `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring your array as `Array<any>` you basically tell TypeScript to back off. `any` is assignable to any type, so when you come to map over your array, you made the assumption that elements are going to be `numbers` and TypeScript is letting you do that by design.

Basically, `any` in TypeScript is an escape hatch that will get TS to shut up and leave things up to you. Generally advised not to use it.

If you expect your array to contain numbers and strings, declare it as `Array<number | string>` and TS will remind you when you go to map over it.

Keep in mind that TypeScript really is not a statically typed compiler, more a "type reminder utility" and therefore can be easily circumvented. For example, this is valid TypeScript:

```js
const a = 12 as any as string;
console.log(a.toLowerCase()); // no TS warnings, only runtime errors
```

Comment: yes, I did not get the error even if I declared the `squares` array as of type numbers    

`let squares : Array<number> = arr.map( (num : number) : number => num * num )`    


this cleared the doubt, i'll stick to JS anyways..

Answer (score 1):

just curious if you expected the error during compile time or runtime?
There is no runtime checking.

Since your array is of type `any`, typescript basically lets you perform all operations of that array (since it does not know its type).

You would be better of declaring your array as `Array<number | string>`. Then there should be an error that you can not multiply two strings.